# extracting particular fields of each record from input file into key/value pairs in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, key, field

The following is the input file to Apache spark processing. each record contains four fields as shown.

```
User ID     Movie ID         Rating      Date
6             9217            2       2005-04-28 00:00:00.000
6             9254            4       2005-04-20 00:00:00.000
6             9330            4       2004-11-17 00:00:00.000
6             9330            5       2004-09-27 00:00:00.000
6             1615            4       2004-09-15 00:00:00.000
6             1659            3       2005-02-18 00:00:00.000
6             9254            4       2005-10-26 00:00:00.000
6             9217            3       2005-11-25 00:00:00.000
6             9217            3       2004-09-15 00:00:00.000
```

from  each of the records, i need to extract  `Movie ID` and `Rating` into key/value pairs as `ex: (Movie ID,Rating )`. i went though the documentation of Apache spark and done some surfing. But couldn't found the relevant stuff. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Think about how you would parse this file without Spark, and then see how you can apply that to an RDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
val text= sc.textFile("movies.txt")
val LogEntry = """^\s*([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+(\d{1})\s+(.*)""".r
val logEntries = text.flatMap(line => line match {
  case LogEntry(userid,movieid,rating,date) => Some((userid.toInt,movieid.toInt,rating.toInt,date))
  case _ => None
}).cache()
val movieTotalRating = logEntries.map(line => line match { case (userid,movieid,rating,date) => (movieid,rating)}).reduceByKey((rating1, rating2) => rating1 + rating2)
```

Notice, I use the `.flatMap` on the `Optional` return type to remove rows which are not matching the RegEx (like the header row)

By caching the `logEntries` you can compute several statistics (like movieTotalRating here) from the same parsed dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it on sample row using pattern matching. But not sure about how to apply to all the lines of input file to generate desired key/value pair (`movie Id, Rating)`.

```
scala> val LogEntry = """^\s*([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+(\d{1})\s+(.*)""".r
LogEntry: scala.util.matching.Regex = ^\s*([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+(\d{1})\s+(.*)

scala> val LogEntry(userid,movieid,rating,date) = "6             9217            2       2005-04-28 00:00:00.000"
userid: String = 6
movieid: String = 9217
rating: String = 2
date: String = 2005-04-28 00:00:00.000
```